# run oracle reports from pl/sql procedure

Tags: plsql, oraclereports

I'm refactoring a very old reports generating function in an ORACLE web application. It used JavaScript to construct a URL, sending to the reports server to run a reports. What I want to do is processing it in the database, in PL/SQL procedures(invoked through `mod_pl/SQL`). I tried to use `utl_http.begin_request` to do that, but sometimes when the output file is large(PDF format, about 20 pages, 1.5M), I received an error:

```
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached.
```

The test codes for sending requests are quite simple:

--------upgraded 2013/08/27----------------------------------------------------------

```
 UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout(1000);
 --some params setting....
 myIdent := SRW.RUN_REPORT(myPlist);  --here raise the exception(ORA-29273:request_failed; ORA-29259: end-of-input reached.) and procedure stoped.
 r_stat := SRW.report_status(myIdent,myPlist);
```

@ThinkJet, Thanks for your help.
I logon the report server, found that the report still running after I got this exception in my program, and finally finished succefully.I tested for many times, and found everytime I got the exception just 5 minutes after I started request,no matter what kind of reports I was running and what size it was (sure, all big size,running for over 5mins).I'm wondering if it's something about configuration on oracle application server?

Does anyone have idea about this? Many Thanks.

Comment: `SRW` is an [event-driven publishing API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_evnt001.htm#i1007523:) package installed with Oracle Reports.

Comment: Did you use [utl_http.write_text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#i1027870) to post some parameters to report and [utl_http.read_raw](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#i1026963) to read data? Can you post exact code used to call report?

Comment: Hi,@ThinkJet,the parameters are already in URL, the 'rpt_url' string in above code is "http://localhost/reports/rwservlet?report=test_report.rdf&userid=usr_name@DB_ID&destype=FILE&desformat=PDF&desname=/apps/app/test/lreports/test_report.pdf&p_name=tester&p_start_date=042013&p_code=L". I just send the request, then the report server will generate a PDF, no need to read or write or download anything.So the test code is exactly the same as above.

Comment: Sorry, no new idea even after update. Can you provide output generated in debug mode by SRW ( [`srw.start_debugging` and `srw.stop_debugging`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/bi.1012/b14048/pbr_evnt.htm#i1007704) )?

Answer (score 1):

ORA-29259 while SRW.RUN_REPORT
is ias 10g , this is cause by httpd.conf timeout parameter configuration
just
1.edit $ORACLE_HOME /Apache/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
change "Timeout"  great than your report running time
2.restart http server and test it.

## opmnctl restartproc ias-component=HTTP_Server

Answer (score 0):

It take a time on Oracle Reports side to produce a big reports so a timeouts can occur sometime. Try to increase timeout with [`utl_http.set_ransfer_timeout` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_http.htm#i1027823) before originate a request and look if it helps.

Comment: Hi @ThinkJet,Thank you for your answer. I did set utl_http.set_ransfer_timeout(1000) before originate requests.Now I installed the SRW package, and use SRW.run_report to do that, still got exception"ORA-29259: end-of-input reached", It dealt with 10 reports one time, 9 of them were OK, only one which got the most data failed.And actually,I found the report successfully generated just several minutes after returning that exception...Do you hava any idea about this? Many thanks..

Comment: @LuLiu Can you please explain more clearly concrete moment when you get this error (e.g. update your question with new code using SRW package and mark a function call producing ORA-29259)? Did you use `SRW.REPORT_STATUS` to check if a report generation has been completed? Any specific information would be helpful to answer to your question.